# Cloud Scheduler invokes Cloud Function more than once during schedule

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, google-cloud-scheduler

I currently have a Cloud Function that is executing some asynchronous code.  It is making a Get request to an Endpoint to retrieve some data and then it storing that data into a Cloud Storage.  I have set up the Cloud Function to be triggered using Cloud Scheduler via HTTP.  When I use the test option that Cloud Function has, everything works fine, but when I set up Cloud Scheduler to invoke the Cloud Function, it gets invoked more than once.  I was able to tell by looking at the logs and it showing multiple `execution id's` and print statements I have in place.  Does anyone know why the Cloud Scheduler is invoking more than once?  I have the `Max Retry Attempts` set to 0.  There is a portion in my code where I use `asyncio's` `create_task` and `sleep` in order to put make sure the tasks get put into the event loop to slow down the number of requests and I was wondering if this is causing Cloud Scheduler to do something unexpected?

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.get_tasks(session=session,page=i)))
        await asyncio.sleep(delay_per_request)
```

Comment: Do you have errors in Cloud Scheduler? What's the duration of your functions? What's the frequency of your Scheduler?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere There was an error, the `jobName` pointed at my Cloud Function, had a `status` of "UNKNOWN" and `targetType` "HTTP".  In the end the Cloud Scheduler successfully ran my Cloud Function, but there was still an error with Cloud Scheduler.  The duration of my function is between 2-3 minutes and the frequency on the scheduler is once a week.  I ended up using a Pub/Sub that triggered my Cloud Function and Cloud Scheduler to invoke the Pub/Sub, this ended up working.

Comment: Status unknown means timeout. You have to update your cloud scheduler config to change that. But it's not normal that there is retries if you set the retry attempt to 0. That's the strangest thing

Comment: there's also the `at least once` execution of event driven Cloud Functions. See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees)

Comment: @EdoAkse It seems my Cloud Function is behaving like this, but the strange part is that if I natively test it (using the test option Cloud Function has) using the feature available it only executes once.   It is only when I run it with Cloud Scheduler I see it execute more than once.

Comment: so the difference there is that when testing, it's not an event driven execution. but with cloud scheduler it is

Comment: @dko512 Since you have a workaround, you can post this as the answer and accept it so that other users in the future can easily see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular case, when natively testing (using the test option cloud function has built-in) my Cloud Function was performing as expected.  However, when I set up Cloud Scheduler to trigger the Cloud Function via a HTTP, it unexpectedly ran more than once.  As @EdoAkse mentioned in original thread [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees) my event with Cloud Scheduler was running more than once.  My solution was to set up Pub/Sub topic that the Cloud Function subscribes to and that topic will trigger that Cloud Function.  The Cloud Scheduler would then invoke that Pub/Sub Trigger.  It is essentially how Google describes it in their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

- Cloud Scheduler -> Pub/Sub Trigger -> Cloud Function

Answer (score 0):

Observed a behavior where cloud functions were being called twice by Cloud Scheduler. Apparently, despite them being located/designated as eu-west1, a duplicate entry in schedule was present for each scheduled function located in us-central1. Removing the duplicated calls in us-central1 resolved my issue.